# php mysql - my code does not update the date which will start from the chosen date

Tags: php, mysql, date, payment

I have a code that will start from the chosen date and ends with the range of how much payment that is preferred by the client to pay for.

Example given: `Amount to pay ($amt) = 70`, `minimum payable ($min) = 35`, `$id =2`,and  `$start_date =  2015-03-03`

```
$duration = $amt / $min;
$start_date = strtotime('2015-03-03');
 for($i=1; $i <= $duration; $i++)
    {
    $start_date = strtotime('+1 day',$start_date);
    $sdate = date("Y-m-d",$start_date);

 mysql_query("UPDATE ledger SET status = 'Paid' where id = '2' and start_date = '$sdate' ");
}
```

This code above will run but dates `2015-03-04` and `2015-03-05` will be marked `Paid`  and does not starts from the date `2015-03-03` til `2015-03-04`. It will jump to the next date, instead. I just want that the start_date will be first to be marked as `Paid`. Please revise my code if its not properly running from what I needed to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a day and only then updating status. So you get date 2015-03-03, add one day and than mark paid, then again add day and again park as paid.
Just put lines in right order

```
for($i=1; $i <= $duration; $i++)
{
    $sdate = date("Y-m-d",$start_date);
    mysql_query("UPDATE ledger SET status = 'Paid' where id = '2' and start_date = '$sdate' ");
    $start_date = strtotime('+1 day',$start_date);
}
```

Comment: Geez, I haven't think about that. Thanks a lot. :) It works. thanks for the help @SeriousDron